# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

using the reveres engineering feature of hibernate in my java web service (running on tomcat)
I get the following error when trying to query my mySQL database:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.users users0_'
>   at line 1

When running :

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Users");  
List<Users> result = q.list();
```

It seems like something was supposed to come before the ".users" mapping.

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml , produced by the reverse engineering process as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="resSession">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ResqueueDBA1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resqueuedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">Resqueue</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">resqueuedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Openinghours" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Branches" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Privileges" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Queues" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Businesses" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Branchservices" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Usersbranchservicesprivilege" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Buisnessservices" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Users" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Buisnessescategories" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Specialevents" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Employeesbranchservicesprivilege" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Employees" />
        <mapping class="com.resqueue.hibernate.Buisnessemployeerole" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the top part of Users class produced by the reverse engineering process as well:

```
package com.resqueue.hibernate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "resqueuedb")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

    ...
```

Probably, something is wrong with my mapping , but I can't find what.
Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: What happened, if you to tried this HQL - `select u from Users u`?

Comment: Are you referring to the correct database, `resqueuedb` where there is table named `users`?

Comment: Yes, The database name is ok and there is a table named "users".as for what Tiny suggested, it throws the same exception.

Comment: Not completely sure, but could you try using `"from users"` instead of `"from Users"` (check the `u` vs `U`)?

Comment: Yes , as i mentioned before - tried using it. and for what you have suggested - Thats not true for HQL queries.